# using a directive to invoke a controller function that displays an alert (probably simple)

Tags: angularjs

I've been following this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/egghead/directives-talking-to-controllers/) and I want to update my code so that the alert is displayed when the button is clicked.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m8n4L7g/15/)

How would I beind the element to a mouse click?  I thought perhaps using something like:

```
.directive('enter', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind("mouseclick", function(){
        scope.$apply("sayHello()");
      })  
   }
})
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.  Should I be using `ng-click` in this case?  I'm trying to follow best practice.  Based on the tutorial I'm following it looks like this is the best way to do this as you can be sure the controller and directive are in the same scope.

I hope this makes sense, I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, ng-click is what you want. With it, your button decalration simply becomes:

```
<button ng-click="sayHello()">sayHello</button>
```

[Here's your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m8n4L7g/19/), it no longer needs the enter directive!